# What values are required in order to send outbound mail via SMTP?

Tags: smtp, outbound-email

I'm trying to get outbound mail set up. With CiviCRM 5.70.1 on PHP8.1, if I configure it to send via mail() then the test message works successfully, but I can see that my transactional emails, a membership receipt email is the one i'm interested in, is getting sent but is malformed (it's like bits of the metadata in the email are missing, resulting in a badly messed up message that is barely readable). I've seen the same thing on a different install, and that was resolved by sending out via SMTP instead, and in that case I get good results by configuring the SMTP settings to use to 'localhost' as my SMTP server on port 25 with no authentication. That's on a server currently running on PHP 7.4 and slightly older version of CiviCRM.

Using the exact same settings on my 5.70.1 install, I get a fatal error. Looking in the logs I see in the CiviCRM log just this:

`[error] not connected`

and in my apache error log I see:

```
Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning:  Undefined property: CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Smtp::$_id in /home/rp/sites/live/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php on line 2123
PHP message: PHP Warning:  Undefined property: CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Smtp::$_id in /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php on line 2123
PHP message: PHP Warning:  Undefined property: CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Smtp::$_id in /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php on line 2123
PHP message: PHP Warning:  Undefined property: CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Smtp::$_id in /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php on line 2123
PHP message: PHP Warning:  Undefined property: CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Smtp::$_id in /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php on line 2123
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function fsockopen() in /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/net_socket/Net/Socket.php:165
```

Clearly CiviCRM is not happy with what I'm providing by way of settings. But it doesn't seem to matter what I put in the SMTP settings fields - I  get the same fatal error regardless. Wondering if this is a bug in 5.70.1?

Comment: What do you have in php.ini for [allow_url_fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) and/or is curl enabled in php.ini's extensions section?

Comment: allow_url_fopen is set to On. cURL support is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Transpires that the user under which the site runs had fsockopen listed as one of the PHP disable_functions. Removing that constraint solved the problem.